# Pattern recognition next shape

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

Is there any logic for finding the next shape in the blank?

I think it's an hard one.

[image]

Comment: What does and does not constitute as a pattern is a matter of opinion, unless you have specific criteria for choosing the next shape, I wouldn't call it a 'solvable' problem.

Comment: @Ethan - well you can look at it as "from all the 4 options which one fit the most to the the blank". i think you can call it a problem.

Comment: It's a problem, it's just not a math problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - sorry for that. thought there's a math logic behind it. thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is chiefly opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments pointed out, these types of problems can be really ambiguous. Here's my guess. Note that out of the four options, the main thing that is different is the number of white shapes. So we need to come up with a rule that tells us how many white shapes should be in the last column.

Scanning along the first row, there seems to be the following rule:

> If there is a white shape in the second column that is in a **different** position compared to a white shape in the first column, then **both** white shapes survive to be in the last column.

Scanning along the second row, there seems to be the following rule:

> If there is a white shape in the second column that is in the **same** position compared to a white shape in the first column, then only **one** of the white shapes survive to be in the last column.

Scanning along the last row, we see that the triangle on the left is in the **same** position in both columns, implying that only **one** of them will be in the last column. Furthermore, we see that the triangle on the right is in a **different** position in both columns, implying that **both** of them will be in the last column.

Thus, my guess is that the answer is the leftmost option labelled $(4)$, since it has $1+2=3$ white triangles.

Comment: that's a nice observation

Comment: Another route to (4): In each column, the number of white symbols on the bottom row is the sum of the number from the first two rows.